# Should I use multiple static classes with maximum one public method

Tags: c#, class, static

I'm writing a structural detailing (CAD) software for concrete buildings in C#. I have defined like hundreds of `static` classes each with one `public method` and if needed some `private methods`. Each one of these methods in these static classes does part of the job. They are called from one God static class named `Building.cs`.

For example one class looks like this:

```
public static partial class GetMainRebars
{
    public static void GetMainRebars()
    {
    }

    // other possible variables and private methods
}
```

The program is running very very fast compared to other similar programs. But deep in my heart, looking at the above code I feel that something still may be wrong with this design pattern. Maybe I will encounter problems in terms of maintenance, or ...? I've taught myself programming, so I may have missed many core principles during the fast self teaching process. Can you elaborate the cons and pros of the above pattern?

And one very rookie question relevant to the pattern. Let's say I define a static variable inside such a class, will it remain in memory during the life time of the program? No disposing and whatsoever? Is it OK?

Comment: What you have written is a structural programming, not object-oriented one (calling sequences of static methods is like calling functions simply). Hence, if it is supposed to be OO-design - it is bad, because there is no object-oriented apporach at all... You necessarily should read about [design patterns](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_Patterns)

Comment: Well, this is roughly the same as having global methods... What you're doing is not object oriented programming, it's procedural programming. Also, having a "god object" (or god class in your case, since it's static) is a known bad practice.

Comment: This link can help you. [link](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/15269/Static-Keyword-Demystified)

Comment: @KonradKokosa Thanks Konrad, I will definitely read that book. Actually I have other non-static classes too and I have used OO-design in some part of the program. But the case here that the classes very very much need the same variables in the Building.cs class. That's why I have defined the variables in the Building.cs as public. What other choices I have here?

Comment: @ThomasLevesque Thanks Thomas, can you read my above comment.

Answer (score 1):

Ok. First of all I want to say that this is a VERY bad pattern (if I can even call it that). You shouldn't have many static classes with single methods... not even gonna talk about the single god static class. You should read up on SOLID principles. For now though I am gonna give you a few pointers.

Instead of having 1000 small static classes, try to group some of them, so you reduce the number a bit(if they have similar function or something of course not otherwise). After that you can turn those static classes into service classes which should derive from interfaces. For example if you have a BuildingService class, you can make it derive from IBuildingService. That way if for some reason in the feature you decide to switch this class out for another one, you can do that without having to change it in a 1000 places but just in one.

Determining which implementation of each interface is going to be used is an IoC(Unity for example)'s job. Also the god class should be removed entirely. Having a class that does 1000 things violates the separation of concern pattern, it doesn't matter if it does them using methods implemented inside other classes or not. If you really need that functionality you can maybe create  class that stores a collection of services which can later be invoked.

I hope this points you in the right direction.